# Do a Google Images search, have it play a full-screen slideshow of the results

Tags: web-apps, osx, web-browser, photography

Is there an OS X application or OS X-compatible browser extension that would allow a user to input a search query  for Google Images and have it immediately begin to display random images from those results in full-screen?

Bonus points if the user can adjust the amount of time per image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a *native* OS X app, but you could try [iSlide](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/islide/goicaghfpnaogbpejmaodednkiilckfo?hl=en), a chrome browser extension.  I used it for a few months now, and I was quite happy with it (although I have a few niggles: like most web browser extensions, I worry about security (even if it states that it uses manifest version 2)).
To quote the blurb from the site:

> Ever got to web page with a thumbnailed image gallery and wanted to
>   view all of the pictures? Like me, you probably had to click each
>   thumbnail, then click on Back, then click on the next thumbnail and so
>   on...  No more! With iSlide you get to watch all the large images with
>   one click! Just click the iSlide icon in the Chrome Extensions toolbar
>   and a slideshow based on the currently selected tab will open in a new
>   tab!

BTW, I would also be interested in a native OS X application too.